# Add number of records in belongs_to relationship in Rail app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, lookup, relationship

I have a Rails simple application that has two main models. A person model and a gift model. Gifts belong to people, and people have many gifts.

I am currently (in the people index view) listing all people in the database with the following code:

```
<% for person in @people %>
<li><%= link_to h(person.name), person %></li>
<% end %>
```

What I would like to do, is have the number of gifts associated to a person next to their name in brackets. Example:

```
Danny McC (10)
```

Is there a built in way of doing this? Such as:

```
<%= @person.name.count =>
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Person model has `has_many :gifts`, in you model also add:

```
de name_and_gifts_count
  name_and_gifts_count = name
  name_and_gifts_count += '('
  name_and_gifts_count += gifts.count.to_s
  name_and_gifts_count += ')'
  return name_and_gifts_count
end
```

then in your link, use:

```
<%= link_to h(person.name_and_gifts_count), person %>
```

Comment: You can make it much shorter. This looks quite ugly IMO... `return "#{name} (#{gifts.count})"`

Comment: @captaintokyo - within the person model again, or within the view?

Comment: In the model: just replace everything that is in the method above with: `return "#{name} (#{gifts.count})"`. Functionality is exactly the same. I just think this looks much better.

Comment: You are missing a double quote... I will add it as an answer, so it's more clear.

Comment: I frequently use this way when building string in order to easily add some logic. For example you can do something like `name_and_gifts_count += gifts.count > 0 ? gifts.count.to_s : 'no picture'` or even replace the 'no picture' string by a link toward the form that allows the upload of pictures…

Answer (score 4):

Don't accept my answer, cause I don't want to steal Yannis' points, but his method *can* be rewritten like this:

```
def name_and_gifts_count
  return "#{name} (#{gifts.count})"
end
```

Actually, I would leave out `return` too. The last statement is automatically returned in Ruby.

```
def name_and_gifts_count
  "#{name} (#{gifts.count})"
end
```